# ASP.NET regular expression - validationExpression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a text box. I added a regular expression to validate the text box that can contain one or 20 characters as below

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regex" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="This contain pipe or more than 20 characters"  
     ValidationExpression="^.{1,20}$"
     ControlToValidate="txtRegexTester" >
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I want to make sure the text box does not contain the PIPE (`|`) symbol also. How do I achieve both in one `ValidationExpression`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe (everything but pipe, 1 or 20 times)

```
"^[^|]{1,20}$"
```

Comment: This probably has better performance than my answer! One note: you don't need to escape the `|` in a character class.